# What's the difference between a console, terminal and command-line?

Tags: command-line, terminal, console, terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between shell, console, and terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/144666/what-is-the-difference-between-shell-console-and-terminal)

My non-tech-savvy friends unanimously agree that *console* refers to hardware and *terminal* refers to software.

[A brief discussion](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1687974#1687974) in a Stack Overflow chatroom yielded inconclusive results.  The terminal-console relationship is reversed, but software is still called a terminal because that's what it's emulating.

What are the differences between consoles and terminals?  Where does *command line* fit in?

Comment: Take a look here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A *terminal* is a hardware device where a human can interface with the computer.

A *terminal emulation* simulates a terminal (e.g. a Gnome-Terminal within the X-Session of an X-Terminal). Terminal emulations are mainly used to achieve two tasks:

1. Simulate a specific terminal on top of annother hardware terminal (to interface with programs that have been written for a specific terminal (for example the command line interface of Stratus systems was heavily dependant on the behaviour of the Televideo 925, but at a certain time that terminal was not manufactured anymore. So they started to sell Qume Terminals that had a builtin Televideo 925 emulation instead).
2. Run multiple terminals although only one pysical terminal is available.

An *X-Windows terminal* is a hardware device capable of running an X-Server.

A *console* is typically a special terminal where the system operator can interface with the system during special tasks like booting or maintenance mode when all other (user-)terminals are unresponsive. Often important notifications from the system are also written to the console terminal.

If one looks at a Linux PC running a graphical user interface, one may find all of the above:

The PC with screen and the keyboard is esentially the console. On the console screen (the PC screen) there are multiple terminal sessions available (accessed typically by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Fn</kbd>).

Additionally there is a X-Server running which enables the graphical user interface (X11 aka. X-Windows) to run on that Linux box. Within that X-Session the user may call programs like *xterm* or *gnome-terminal* which are basically terminal emulations of a *DEC VT220* terminal. (xterm is also capable of emulating the *Tektronix 4014* graphics terminal, in real life a real HW-monster back then).

Comment: Forgot about the command line: That's simple a command based interface of any kind. Examples may be the the DOS-Prompt or the UNIX shell, but also the command interface of tools like ftp (the non-GUI version).