# what is the difference between terminal in Mac OS X and Ubuntu

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, terminal

Both Mac OS X and Ubuntu (and other Linus OS) has terminal / command line.

Are these terminal identical across different OS? If not, what are the important difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Terminal emulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) provides an interface to run a [shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29), which again is an interface to access your operating system functions.

Terminals used to be real machines, e.g. a monitor with a keyboard attached, which sent your keystrokes to the actual computer at the other end, and receiving output from this computer. For example, the famous [VT100](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100):

[image]

Nowadays, this is emulated by those applications, like the *Terminal.app* on OS X, or GNOME Terminal for the GNOME graphical interface on Linux distributions.

As it's decoupled from the shell that you can run (e.g. [*bash*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29), [*zsh*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsh), *...*), you are free to use any other terminal emulator. For example, on OS X, you can use [iTerm 2](http://www.iterm2.com/), which offers a bit more than the normal terminal application.

As the terminal is the bridge between your GUI and the text-only shell, its functionality should go beyond accepting keyboard input and displaying output from the shell. A terminal *should* supply you with means of:

- copying and pasting to the GUI
- sending special commands to the shell (so called [escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence); your terminal will for example map `Cmd - Right Arrow` to an appropriate shell sequence to go to the end of the line*)
- allowing other shortcuts with hotkeys
- allowing the shell to track the mouse
- allowing multiple tabs with different shells running at the same time
- allowing you to drag a file icon to the shell to get its real path
- notifying the GUI of events (such as a blinking screen, or [Growl output](http://growl.info/))
- etc.

To sum it up: Different terminals offer different functionality with regards to how they interact with your operating system on the one hand, and the shell on the other hand. You can find a [comparison of terminal emulators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_terminal_emulators) on Wikipedia.

That being said, there isn't an important difference. Most people set up terminals to their liking, e.g. some like a transparent background, whereas others don't. Some like them to display their shell black on white, others rather like it green on black.**
Some terminals allow you to set up different keyboard shortcut profiles, or even other profiles that launch different shells on startup, with a different windows size, etc.

---

<sub>* Note that this is a rather simplified statement. The terminal just needs to find a way to map special keys – especially on Macs, where there's a `Command` key – to commands a shell can understand.</sub>

<sub>** This is also a functionality of the terminal: Displaying colors. You can actually tweak your terminal to show stuff the shell intended to be *green* as *red* instead. It's primarily a matter of customization.</sub>

Comment: Windows console as in `CON`?

Comment: @DanielBeck Isn't it [that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682010(v=VS.85).aspx)? If not, please enlighten me, I really don't know much about Windows here.

Comment: No idea, that's why I'm asking. I only know of the DOS device name, and that writing to it (`echo foo > con`) makes the output non-redirectable later.

Comment: Windows is a wholly different ball game, since it and its predecessors never really had the full glass TTY paradigm in the first place.  I recommend simply taking that sentence out of your answer.  It's misleading at best, and explaining Windows is not really within the purview of this question in the first place.

Comment: @jdeBP Done so. How does it work on Windows then?

Comment: I haven't looked to see whether it's already covered.  If it's not, it's worth doing a proper question for this.  A Windows version of [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/144666/) perhaps.  Have a look to see whether there's already a question for this.

Answer (score 1):

note: the **terminal** is a wrapper program which runs the shell. the term derives from times where it still was a physical device (keyboard).

the **shell** (or command interpreter) runs commands and returns the results. you basically can run the same shells on both operating systems:

- bash
- csh
- ksh
- zsh

shells of the mentioned operating systems (in question tags) are all using the same core commands because they are UNIX-like and have to fulfill the [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) standard. this is why you will feel familiar on both OSs.

Comment: You haven't said a word about what the difference between terminals would be. You're only talking about shells. Shells are not terminals.

Comment: OS X uses `bash` as the default shell for all users, so your links are misleading. Almost all programs that are mentioned in the lists are independent of the shell used.

Comment: thanks. removed links. note: even bash is the default shell, you can use a different shell if you like.