# How to use different key maps for different devices?

Tags: linux

My laptop has a US built-in keyboard and I am also connecting a good old Cherry keyboard with German key layout via a PS/2-to-USB adapter. Is there a way to install different keymaps used in the Linux text console for the different devices simultaneously?

Comment: It's been a while I've done this, but back in the day, I had 2 keyboards, french, and english, never got them to work together like you'd like but, when one is plugged in, I'd replace it by the other. 

 

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=84163 

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap

Comment: Which text consoles? There are like 5!! Console, TTY, Terminal, Shell, etc. http://superuser.com/q/144666/235569

Comment: As far as I can tell, the keyboard layout is set using loadkeys, and is associated with the virtual console, rather than the keyboards.  Otherwise you would use udev to make any changes when the USB device is detected as being inserted / added as a device.  I hate to say it, but I don't see a way to do i

Answer (score -1):

You have to find the ID device:

`xinput -list | grep -i key`

and using such ID set the layout:

`setxkbmap -device ID -layout layout`

Comment: Right, that's for X11. I am looking for the corresponding procedure for the text-console.

Comment: Reason for downvote: answers another question.