# Create nested directory from parent directory in Windows 7 when using Bash in Cmdr

Tags: windows, command-line, cmder

First I do this:

```
mkdir firstFolder
```

Then:

```
mkdir firstFolder/secondFolder
```

Here an error occurs. The command line interface returns "incorrect syntax". What is the right syntax?

I am using Bash upon [Cmdr](https://cmder.net/) in Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You think it's Bash but maybe it's not. CMD in Windows has `mkdir` too but the directory separator is `\`.

Try

```
mkdir firstFolder\secondFolder
```

In Bash the backslash would be interpreted as (unnecessary) escape character, the command would create a directory named `firstFoldersecondFolder`. If it creates `secondFolder` inside `firstFolder` then you're not in Bash.

Comment: Okay I have understood that Cmder - https://www.cmder.net -  was a kind of bash for Windows

Comment: @Webwoman It's a terminal emulator. I don't know the program at all but I expect one can choose somehow which shell it starts. Useful resource: [*What is the difference between shell, console, and terminal?*](https://superuser.com/q/144666/432690)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to create the whole tree in one go and avoid the error:

```
mkdir -p firstFolder/secondFolder/thirdFolder
```

The `-p` parameter is defined as:

```
-p, --parents     no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

Note: This depends on how close to the Linux standard is implemented `mkdir` in your environment.

Comment: I thought this was a `-p` issue as well, but as the original poster confirms in [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1505364/create-nested-directory-from-parent-directory-with-bash#comment2274600_1505364), switching from forward slash (`/`) to a backslash (`\`) fixed the issue.

Comment: @JakeGould: Misled by the reference to bash.