# How to select text or scroll without pressing Ctrl+M when "Quick edit" is disabled?

Tags: terminal, powershell, cmd.exe, selection

I unchecked "Quick edit" button in properties because it was freezing PowerShell. But now I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> every time I want to scroll or select a text which is a pain in the ass if you are working with it all the times. Is there a way to fix it?

(It is the same with CMD too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark mode is a feature of the *terminal/console* and has nothing to do with the *shell*. A shell (such as cmd or PowerShell) has to connect/attach to some terminal to do console work. See [What is the difference between shell, console, and terminal?](https://superuser.com/q/144666/241386)

The terminal is [conhost.exe](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/4996/what-is-conhost.exe-and-why-is-it-running/) on Windows by default, which blocks when the user selects texts so regardless of which shell you're using you'll always be blocked if you click inside the terminal or press some text selection shortcut

So the simplest solution is to avoid clicking inside conhost.exe for no reason and only do that when you want to select texts. But the better way is to change to a more superior terminal that doesn't block on text selection like [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal). Some other alternatives being git or MSYS' terminal, or the built-in terminal of VS Code. Of course now selecting text while a long command is running would be much more difficult